# SDL2 Wrapper class complains `Invalid Renderer`

Tags: c++, wrapper, sdl-2

I'm trying to write a C++ wrapper class around some SDL2 classes.

Now I have this working code, which displays a red screen for 5 seconds (as you can see, my wrapper classes are in namespace `sdl2cc`):

```
int main(void)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) return 1;

    sdl2cc::Window window{"SDL_RenderClear"s, sdl2cc::Rect{sdl2cc::Point{SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED}, sdl2cc::Dimension{512, 512}}, {}};
    sdl2cc::Renderer renderer{window, {}};

    renderer.draw_color(sdl2cc::Color{sdl2cc::RGB{255,0,0}, sdl2cc::Alpha{255}});

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer.data());
    // renderer.clear();

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer.data());
    // renderer.present();

    SDL_Delay(5000);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

In the wrapper class of SDL2's `SDL_Renderer` I have a `std::unique_ptr` data member `renderer_` pointing to an actual `SDL_Renderer`.

`renderer.data()` exposes this pointer (`return this->renderer_.get();`).

I want to get the member functions `renderer.clear()` and `renderer.present()` to work. Sadly neither do. This is how they look:

```
void sdl2cc::Renderer::clear(void)
{
    if (SDL_RenderClear(this->data()) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't clear rendering target with drawing color:" << ' ' << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
    }
}

void sdl2cc::Renderer::present(void)
{
    SDL_RenderPresent(this->data());
}
```

If I just use `renderer.clear()`, it will print my error message + *Invalid renderer*.

If I just use `renderer.present()`, it will show a black screen.

What is wrong?

Why are my own functions and the SDL functions not equivalent?

---

The problem seems to lie in the function call:

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer.data()); // works

// somewhere else:
void sdl2cc::Renderer::clear(SDL_Renderer* r)
{
    if (SDL_RenderClear(r) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't clear rendering target with drawing color:" << ' ' << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
    }
}

renderer.clear(renderer.data()); // doesn't work: Invalid Renderer
```

But I still don't understand where the problem lies. To me it seems to accomplish the same thing, but somehow one throws an error, the other doesn't.

---

EDIT:
Another interesting thing, trying to step in at `renderer.clear()` with `lldb` goes directly to the next line, without actually stepping in... I don't even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with multiply linked libraries.
I compiled my own library with the SDL2 libraries and then compiled my executable with my library *and* the SDL2 libraries.